# How to create patch from all changes commited by specified user(s) after specified date(revision,tag) using SVN repository

Tags: svn

How to create patch from all changes commited by specified user(s) after specified date(revision,tag) using SVN repository.
My ide is Eclipse and Intellij Idea , but tortoise is also accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your user name is "test" and you want to identify what all files are changed between some specified dates

```
svn log <url> --username test -qv -r {2010-11-01}:{2011-05-04} > log.txt
```

Comment: Doing this will correctly give you a list of the modified files, but not a patch as asked in the question...

Answer (score 0):

If PowerShell is an acceptable option, here is a script that will do the job:

```
$RepoAddr = "https://url/to/your/repo";
$FromRev = "140";
$ToRev = "HEAD";
$WantedAuthor = "yannick";
$PatchFile = "$($WantedAuthor).patch";

$CmdLine = "svn log -r$($FromRev):$($ToRev) $RepoAddr --xml";
$Logs = ([xml](Invoke-Expression $CmdLine));

foreach ($Commit in $Logs.log.logentry)
{
    [string]$TmpAuth = $Commit.author;
    if ($TmpAuth.CompareTo($WantedAuthor) -eq 0)
    {
        [int] $TmpRev = $Commit.revision;
        $PatchCmdLine = "svn diff -r$($TmpRev-1):$TmpRev $RepoAddr";
        Write-Host $PatchCmdLine;
        Invoke-Expression $PatchCmdLine | Out-File $PatchFile -append;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!!